# Why does del produce UnboundLocalError for parameters?

Tags: python, del

There is a python closure function:

```
def test(a):
    def delete():
        print "first", a
    delete()
    print "second", a

test(1)
```

And the output is:

```
first 1
second 1
```

Then we try another function:

```
def test(a):
    def delete():
        print "first", a
        del a
    delete()
    print "second", a

test(1)
```

And we get the output:

```
UnboundLocalError  
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-c61f724ccdbf> in <module>()
      6     print "second", a
      7 
----> 8 test(1)

<ipython-input-28-c61f724ccdbf> in test(a)
      3         print "first", a
      4         del a
----> 5     delete()
      6     print "second", a
      7 

<ipython-input-28-c61f724ccdbf> in delete()
      1 def test(a):
      2     def delete():
----> 3         print "first", a
      4         del a
      5     delete()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Why does the variable **a** turn to be a local variable before **del**?

Please notice that the error is in line

```
print "first", a
```

but not

```
del a
```

Comment: I guess doing `del a` has the same effect as `a = ...` in this regard.

Comment: Modifying a variable implies that it's local in scope. You can use the `global` keyword to access the outer scope `a`.

Comment: @tzaman, Please notice that the error is in line print "first", a, but not del a. That's my question.

Comment: @Tyler the `UnboundLocalError` shows up at the first usage of the variable, since it's been determined to be a local but you're using it before assigning. See the linked dupe for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The name `a` is local to the scope of `test()` but not to the scope of `delete()`.

Since you try to `del a`, Python *assumes* `a` to be local, which it is not.

Finally you get the error on `print "first", a` since a is assumed to be local but not defined before printing it at this point.

Comment: That sounds make sense.